# How to clear input field field after search query and display all list items at the same time when clicking back to the input

Tags: javascript, search, input

I have a multi select with search functionality and dropdown menu. I can clear the input field once a user searched for an item and selected it. But the problem is, once you click back to the input field, you are seeing that last selected item instead of the whole list. I would like to display the whole list of items. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Here's the filter function:

```
filterOptions() {

    this.dom.select.classList.add('open');
    this.dom.select.classList.remove('closed');

    const items = Array.from(this.dom.items);
    const typedValue = this.dom.input.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    this.filteredOptions = items.filter(val => val.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(typedValue) > -1);

    if (this.filteredOptions.length) {

      this.dom.selectOptions.innerHTML = '';

      for (let i = 0; i < this.filteredOptions.length; i += 1) {

        if (typedValue !== this.filteredOptions[i].innerText.trim().toLowerCase()) {

          this.filteredOptions[i].classList.remove('active');

        } else {

          this.filteredOptions[i].classList.add('active');
        }

        this.dom.selectOptions.appendChild(this.filteredOptions[i]);
      }

    } else {
      this.dom.selectOptions.innerHTML = '<div class="no_results">No results found</div>';
    }
  }
```

Selecting multiple options:

```
multiSelect(target) {
    const optionsArr = this.selectedOptions;
    const li = target.closest('.item');
    const input = li.querySelector('input');
    const itemValue = input.value;
    const typedValue = this.dom.input.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    if (target.tagName !== 'INPUT') {
      input.checked = !input.checked;
    }

    li.classList.toggle('active', input.checked);

   if (input.checked) {
      this.dom.input.value = '';
    } 

    if (optionsArr.indexOf(itemValue) === -1) {
      optionsArr.push(itemValue);
    } else {
      optionsArr.splice(optionsArr.indexOf(itemValue), 1);
    }

  }
```

I've tried several different approaches, but can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: Where's the corresponding HTML? Please provide a [mre] — see [ask]. A runnable [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) allows anyone to see the problematic behavior that you're describing — can you update the question to include one?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.